Supabase Authentication "Email rate limit exceeded" preventing development
Is there a way to get by "Email rate limit exceeded" issue in Supabase temporarily? I am developing a sign up feature, and after 2 sign ups, I am getting this error and I can't continue development now.

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-smtp

At present, you can trial the Supabase platform by sending up to 3 emails per hour via the built-in service. The default email service as a whole is offered on a best effort basis: we will do our best to maintain it and will review usage of the service on a regular basis to see if the email service should be continued.
As you progress toward production, you may find yourself wanting for a custom SMTP service in order to increase your limits. A custom SMTP server will allow you to set your own cap on the number of emails sent per hour.

